# how to use DB value in .css files using vuejs typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to get color from DB and assign it to my external .css files. There is no proper solution exist on the Internet.
below is my js code

```
  createBackgroundHeaderColor() {
return  `linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 0%, ${this.data.setting.hbgColor} 90%)`;}
```

here is my code to get value from DB.
below is my CSS code

```
.focused {
        background: createBackgroundHeaderColor !important;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a computed method and return the style object then you can directly apply inline style. something like.

```
<div :style="myStyles"> </dv>
```

and

```
computed: {
  myStyles(){
    //you can add your focus condition here
    return {"background": createBackgroundHeaderColor}
  }
}
```